# is it possible to display pictures in a popup.php window, using the src from the main page?

Tags: javascript, popup, window

I have a page with pictures, which I want to displayed in a popup.php when clicking on them.
I want the popup window to display a picture(the one I'm clicking on), some text, and a print button. 
I'm doing this on the page:

`<a href="#" onClick="popup()"><img src="graphics/picture1.png" width="340" height="200" border="0"/></a>`

In the JS file:

```
function popup()
{
window.open('popup.php', 'window', 'toolbar=no,location=no,status=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=no,resizable=no,width=520,height=400,left=350,top=100');
}

function showImg(img) 
{
  var imageSrc = "imageName/imagePath.png";
  if(img.src != imageSrc){ 
    img.src = imageSrc;
  }
}
```

And in the popup.php:

```
<img src="graphics/picture03.png" onload="showImg(this)" />
```

There should be an obvious way, but I can't find it.

Answer (score 0):

I would think adding the image name and text content to the URL would be the obvious way.

```
popup.php?image=myImage.gif&text=Say%20something%20witty%20here
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you'll want to have your popup contain a holder for the image (which it seems like you already have), but you'll also need to have a holder for your text. Your popup.php should have something like `<div id="textHolder"></div>` - then your javascript function needs to accept the appropriate text as well as populate it into the `textHolder` div.

I'm not sure how you're calling these JS functions, or from where - so some of the code might need to change - it should be something to the tune of....

```
function showImg(img, textHolderObj, text) 
{
  var imageSrc = "imageName/imagePath.png";
  if(img.src != imageSrc){ 
    img.src = imageSrc;
  }
  textHolderObj.innerHTML= text
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If is that simple, you could create it:

```
var win = window.open('', 'win', 'toolbar=no,location=no,status=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=no,resizable=no,width=520,height=400,left=350,top=100');

var img = win.document.createElement('img');
    img.src = 'image.png';
    img.alt = 'Some text';

var label = win.document.createElement('p');
    label.innerHTML = 'Some text';

var button = win.document.createElement('a');
    button.href = 'javascript:window.close()';
    button.innerHTML = 'Close';

win.document.body.appendChild(img);
win.document.body.appendChild(label);
win.document.body.appendChild(button);
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't get the question too well. You want to access a function that was defined in the page that opened a popup? You should be able to use `opener.showImg(this)`

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to create a new popup window using a variable

```
top.mydocument=window.open('','window','toolbar=no,location=no,
status=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=no,resizable=no,
width=520,height=400,left=350,top=100');
```

and then use `document.write` to write the content:

```
top.mydocument.document.write(
  '&lt;html&gt;&lt;head&gt;&lt;/head&gt;'
   +'&lt;body bgcolor=white onLoad="self.focus()"&gt;'
   +'imageName/imagePath.png'
   +'&lt;/body&gt;&lt;/html&gt;'
 )
```

Make sure you close it.

```
top.mydocument.document.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

your popup has no idea what image you clicked on. you need to do this:

```
onClick="popup('imgSrc')"
```

and in your window reference:

```
window.open('popup.php?imgSrc='+imgSrc, ...
```

then... your popup window has to run off of url vars, but php now knows what its looking for:

```
<?php echo '<img src="' . $_GET["imgSrc"] . '" />';  // this is going to load the image, so you don't need the onLoad()
```